# marklogic 6 - How to load the xml document from share path location to marklogic DB

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have tried the below mentioned Xquery for load the XML file from local system to MarkLogic database:

```
xdmp:document-load("D:/scrape/100065.xml",
  <options xmlns="xdmp:document-load">
    <uri>/April/12/100065.xml</uri>
    <encoding>auto</encoding>
     </options>)
```

How to provide the share path location instead of local system path?

Comment: It is simple. Just go on shared directory to check its network path by clicking its property (as you normally do at the time of folder sharing to others) and refer that path into your XQuery.

Comment: Thanks Navin I will check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things to note:

- the path must be visible where MarkLogic is installed. That is, if you're loading on a remote server, remember that MarkLogic will look at the filesystem on that server
- use backslashes for the Windows path, [as seen in the first and third examples](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-load).

XQuery:

```
xdmp:document-load("D:\scrape\100065.xml",
  <options xmlns="xdmp:document-load">
    <uri>/April/12/100065.xml</uri>
   <encoding>auto</encoding>
  </options>
)
```